# GoogleApiClient cannot be resolved

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-client

I am working in Google App Indexing for my project.

Newbee for this feature. I just following the google guide lines.

[Notify the google using API](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/appindexingapi)

In this page,asked to create an instance of GoogleApiClient. I tried but getting "GoogleApiClient cannot be resolved a type" error.

And I have added the following libraries into my project.

1.Google play services
2.Google api client
3.Google http api client

[image: Installed Google APIs]

and

[image: Libraries included]

the error is

[image: Error image]

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Have you added the jar file in build path ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Copy the library project at    /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/ to the location where you maintain your Android app projects (your projects folder).
- Import the library project into your Eclipse workspace. Click File >    Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace, and    browse to the copy of the library project to import it (browse to the google-play-services_lib folder).
- In your app project, reference Google Play services library project (right click on project, Properties, Android, click on Add..., select google-play-services_lib folder).
- After you've added the Google Play services library as a dependency for your app project, open your app's manifest file and add the following tag as a child of the  element (this is a new requirement as of updated Google Play Services):

  ```
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
  ```

Then add this statement in your class (or fix the error):

`import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient`

For Android Studio, follow directions here:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 1):

If you update SDK all...

1. Remove "google-play-services.jar" in libs directory.
2. Import google-play-services_lib project in SDK ([your-sdk]\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib)
3. Click your Project > Right Click > Properties > Click Android > Click [Add] button in the Library section and add google play library.
4. And... Fix the Red alerts(?) :)

I hope this helps you...